# Are there any non-blocking node.js db drivers for redis, mongo or mysql?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, nosql

I know there are blocking drivers for these and have used them but am looking for non-blocking node drivers.  thanks.

Comment: The standard couch & mongo drivers block? Do we even care about that as long as the IO node.js uses is non bloocking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-blocking MySql drivers:

native JS, non-blocking due to event loop

- http://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
- https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native
- https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2

libmysqlclient bindings, non-blocking with node thread pool

- http://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient

libmariasql bindings:

- https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/

Answer (score 6):

[node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) is an excellent, non-blocking Node driver for MongoDB.  It also contains optional C-based BSON extensions for performance.

Comment: OK thanks much - knew it had perf enhancements - did not know that it was non-blocking.

Answer (score 4):

[https://github.com/mranney/node_redis](http://node_redis)

> For portability, a pure JavaScript
>   reply parser is used by default.
>   Pieter Noordhuis has provided a
>   binding to the official hiredis C
>   library, which is non-blocking and
>   fast. To use hiredis, do:

```
npm install hiredis redis
```

### Performance

hiredis parser:

```
PING: 20000 ops 46189.38 ops/sec 1/4/1.082 
SET: 20000 ops 41237.11 ops/sec 0/6/1.210 
GET: 20000 ops 39682.54 ops/sec 1/7/1.257 
INCR: 20000 ops 40080.16 ops/sec 0/8/1.242
LPUSH: 20000 ops 41152.26 ops/sec 0/3/1.212 
LRANGE (10 elements): 20000 ops 36563.07 ops/sec 1/8/1.363
LRANGE (100 elements): 20000 ops 21834.06 ops/sec 0/9/2.287
```

Comment: OK, thanks much again knew that it was high perf but not that it was non-blocking.  Thanks much